# MS Access VBA using ADODB connection string - field1 = "xyz" not updating the table

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb

I have a front end .accdb file connecting to back end data via ADODB.connection.  SQL SELECT statements are working fine to create ADODB.recordsets but when I use SQL to select just one record that I want to update, code similar to: field1 = "xyz" doesn't error but neither does it update the table data in the back end .accdb database file.  I can update the backend data tables using .Execute but I prefer working with .recordsets.

this is how I create my recordset that I want to loop through and update using simple Filed1 = "field1 value" for each field that I want to update.

```
Dim strStackPath As String
Dim ADOrstStack As ADODB.Recordset
Set ADOrstStack = New ADODB.Recordset
ADOrstStack.Open "SELECT * FROM tblDocLibUndoStack ORDER BY f_UndoStackNumber", ADOcnn0, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

But I've had to use the .Execute code below to update the data.

```
ADOcnn0.Execute "UPDATE tblDocLibUndoStack SET f_UndoStack = '" & strStack & "' WHERE f_UndoStackNumber = " & ADOrstStack!f_UndoStackNumber + 1
```

By the way, I'll add the connection string I am using, scavenged from looking at the string generated by

```
CurrentProject.AccessConnection

ADOstr0 = "Provider='Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0';Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=C:\...Data.accdb;User ID=Admin;Data Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
```

Comment: You need to show the full SQL --- you can have a query that is not updatable...

Comment: The recordset is created by: ADOrstStack.Open "SELECT * FROM tblDocLibUndoStack ORDER BY f_UndoStackNumber", ADOcnn0, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Comment: I can update this recordset using .Execute but not using Field1 = "xyz"

Comment: .Execute is:
ADOcnn0.Execute "UPDATE tblDocLibUndoStack SET f_UndoStack = '" & strStack & "' WHERE  f_UndoStackNumber = " & ADOrstStack!f_UndoStackNumber + 1

Comment: Maybe I don't understand... Your '.Execute' (that you showabove) works just fine? But vba code like 'ADOrstStack!Field1 = "xyz" and ADOrstStack.Update doesn't work - is that correct?  Seeing only glimpses of part of your code makes it tough. I assume you have the ".Update" code?

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, edit your question instead. @DonaldWGarton

Comment: ...apologies if I am missing the obvious Wayne

Comment: Don't take this wrong, but it is extremely difficult to diagnose a problem without seeing all code that is related to the issue you face. Without the code, we have to either assume certain things are correct/wrong, or we have to *believe* what the OP is telling us. In my case, I have a special disdain for relying on 'no changes'. I spent six months unsuccessfully trying to solve a problem for a large corporation, only to ask AGAIN 'did you change something?' and the sheepish reply was 'yes, but that couldn't matter'.  Where is your UPDATE code that fails?

Comment: Wayne ...I think I am confused - been rewriting DAO code to ADO for the past week with no prior experience with ADO.  I think I have it working ok now.  Yes the .Update was missing.  I thought I had read somewhere that it wasn't used in ADO...

Comment: It's the .Edit that is not needed... Glad it's working!!  There was a great article from Microsoft re conversion from DAO to ADO, with samples, but the link no longer works... but I placed the code samples at this link:  http://1anddunn.com/DAOtoADO.txt

Comment: thank you very much for that link Wayne, regards Donald